# How to run mapreduce under namespace?

Tags: google-app-engine, mapreduce

I want to run mapreduce to change datastore entity under namespace in google app engine with python.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The appengine mapreduce supports `namespace` option. You'll need to check the version you installed to be sure. From the latest version, put the `namespace` parameter in the mapper param. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-mapreduce/blob/master/python/src/mapreduce/input_readers.py#L320

Comment: Thanks! This helps.